How can I modify my WKWebView when using them in combination with a TabView?
The main view of my app consists of a TabView where most of the views are native and two are web views. Users need to login first, after which cookies are fetched and used during the creation of the web views so users are logged in there as well. The problem is when the app becomes active again from the background. As it continued to be in memory the web views still exist with old, expired cookies. Fetching fresh cookies when the app becomes active again is no problem, but I'm having difficulty on how to set the cookies on the already existing web views.
The ContentView looks like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authModel: AuthModel

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ExampleOneView() // Native view
                .tabItem {
                    Label("One", systemImage: "house")
                }

            ExampleTwoView() // Also native
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Two", systemImage: "house")
                }

            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://\(authModel.server)/home")!)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Three", systemImage: "house")
                }

            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://\(authModel.server)/me")!)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Four", systemImage: "house")
                }
        }
    }
}

And the WebView:
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var authModel: AuthModel
    
    var url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        for cookie in authModel.cookies {
            configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
        }

        return WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}

The idea is to change the ContentView like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                ExampleOneView() // Native view
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("One", systemImage: "house")
                    }

                ExampleTwoView() // Also native
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Two", systemImage: "house")
                    }

                WebView(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/home")!)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Three", systemImage: "house")
                    }

                WebView(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/me")!)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Four", systemImage: "house")
                    }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { oldPhase, newPhase in
            if newPhase == .active {
                Task {
                    await authModel.retrieveCookies()
                    // I don't have access to the web views, so I don't know how to set the fresh cookies
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit
Looking into this some more I read the documentation for the WKWebViewConfiguration and it seems to suggest that it can't be changed after initializing the WebView because the returned object is a copy.
I did stumble on a solution that looks promising, and that is using WKWebsiteDataStore. It seems that it is used by all WebViews to store cookies. To test this I've removed the code that sets the cookies in the makeUIView(context:) method of the WebView struct and added the following code to the retrieveCookies() method of the AuthModel.
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
}

Because all WKWebViews use the WKWebsiteDataStore I'm still logged in in the WebView without setting the cookies directly on it. This way the current implementation of the onChange(of:) method that calls the retrieveCookies() should be enough the refresh the cookies for all WebViews. Would this be a suitable solution or are the any caveats and/or pitfalls that I need to take into account?

Could could add a @State bool var to the WebView that tells it to update the cookies on the next UI update.
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var authModel: AuthModel
    @State var shouldRefreshCookies = true
    
    var url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        return WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if shouldRefreshCookies {
            for cookie in authModel.cookies {
                configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
            }
            shouldRefreshCookies = false
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @State var webViewHomeTab = WebView(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/home")!)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                webViewHomeTab
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Three", systemImage: "house")
                    }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { oldPhase, newPhase in
            if newPhase == .active {
                Task {
                    await authModel.retrieveCookies()
                    webViewHomeTab.shouldRefreshCookies = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Why is the shouldRefreshCookies state variable necessary in the WebView? With the webviews in state variables in the ContentView it's possible to set the cookies in the onChange directly, right? The URLs used for the webviews are build dynamically depending on the server selected during login, so making state variables for the webviews is a little difficult. I forgot to add that in the question, sorry.
